# AngularJs: Set focus manually to input text

Tags: javascript, angularjs, focus

I need to set the focus on the input element manually. I am using `$event.currentTarget.focus();` but I don't know why it is not working. This is what I am doing:

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items track by $index" ng-dblclick="onDblClick($event,item)">
      <input type="text" ng-model="item.id" ng-disabled="!item.editing" ng-blur="onBlur(item)">
    </div>
```

**Script:**

```
$scope.onDblClick = function($event, item) {
      item.editing = true;
      //setting the focus to elemnt but don't know why it's not working
      $event.currentTarget.focus();
    };
```

Here is the [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/VY03HdmUHyw6r4s0qpXk?p=preview).

Comment: It seems to be working?What exactly do you need?

Comment: It is just enabling the text box but not focusing it. If you see when you double click the input element is getting enabled. But if you click anywhere apart from the enable input element than ideally it should loose focus and the ngBlur callback should be fired but it's not happening.

Comment: nevermind, I misunderstood :) (edited away what I wrote)

Comment: @klskl sorry I did not get you.

Answer (score 0):

Anyways I figured out by my self. I created a directive `focus` and set a `$watch`.

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items track by $index" ng-dblclick="onDblClick($event,item)">
      <input type="text" ng-model="item.id" ng-disabled="!item.editing" ng-blur="onBlur(item)" focus="item.editing">
    </div>
```

**Script:**

```
app.directive('focus', function($timeout) {
    return function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      console.log(attrs)
      scope.$watch(attrs.focus, function(newval) {
        if (newval) {
          $timeout(function() {
            elem[0].focus();
          }, 0, false);
        }
      });
    };
  });
```

Here's the [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/cbG88NR9RL5SirxuAO4X?p=preview).